# cakephp disable direct access to a controller

Tags: cakephp, controller, element

I am new to use cakephp2,
i use element + requestAction to show a news block on some page of my site, like below:

news.ctp

```
<?php
$news = $this->requestAction('controller'=>'News','action'=>'load');

foreach($news as $itm){
    echo $itm['title];
    //...
}
```

NewsController.php

```
<?php
//...
public function load(){
    //...
    return $data;
}
```

It's worked well ,my problem is

**how to disable direct access** like: `http://domain/News/load`

and if it is a good way to make a contents block?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller you can try like this to prevent direct access.

```
public function load(){
    if (empty($this->request->params['requested'])) {
        $this->redirect($this->referer());
    }
    return $data;
}
```

If `requestAction` is used without caching requestAction can lead to poor performance. It is rarely appropriate to use in a controller or model. check [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller%3a%3arequestAction)

For more info you can check the documentation [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#controller-actions)